# 'Not an ARRAY reference' error thrown

Tags: mysql, perl

I'm writing a Perl script that is meant to deal with an API which returns metrics about a set of URLs that I pull from MySQL then post these metrics back into a different table. Currently this piece of code:

```
my $content = $response->content;

my $jsontext = json_to_perl($content);

my $adsql = 'INSERT INTO moz (url_id,page_authority,domain_authority,links,MozRank_URL,MozRank_Subdomain,external_equity_links) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
my $adrs = $db->prepare( $adsql );

my $adsql2 = 'UPDATE url 
SET moz_crawl_date = NOW()
where url_id = ?;';
my $adrs2 = $db->prepare( $adsql2 );

my $currentUrlId = 0;

foreach my $row (@$jsontext){
    $adrs->execute($url_ids[$currentUrlId], $row->{'fmrp'}, $row->{'upa'}, $row->{'pda'}, $row->{'uid'}, $row->{'umrp'}, $row->{'ueid'});# || &die_clean("Couldn't execute\n$adsql\n".$db->errstr."\n" );
    $adrs2->execute($url_ids[$currentUrlId]);
    $currentUrlId++;
}
```

is throwing this error:

```
Not an ARRAY reference at ./moz2.pl line 124.
```

this is line 124:

```
foreach my $row (@$jsontext){
```

this whole chunk of code is in a `while` loop.  I am actually able to iterate a couple times and fill my MySQL table before the script fails (technically the program works, but I don't want to just leave an error in it).

Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: What is the value of `$content` when you get this error? The error implies that it's not a JSON array.

Comment: Line breaks, there not just a suggestion.

Comment: either a hash or a string that looks like a hash.  When I print it out it looks like this:  [{"fmrp":6.182095114661029,"fmrr":8.22438062351392e-08,"pda":58.91591252161899,"ueid":5831,"uid":480143,"umrp":6.63361336728684,"umrr":1.869832885935372e-08,"upa":65.70993919657755}]

Comment: That value for `$content` is fine, and `$jsontext` *would* be an array reference if that was the case. Are you sure you're not corrupting `$jsontext` before it gets used? Or perhaps your HTTP message has an empty body? In that case `$jsontext` would be `undef`. It sounds like you may be making a series of HTTP requests, and the final one may be indicated by an empty body. Just guessing here...

Comment: You were right! I had a problem with my while loop but now its resolved, thanks!

Comment: Please add an answer if you've solved it. It's ok to self answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perl gave you the correct answer

`Not an ARRAY reference: @$jsontext`

You are dereferencing `$jsontext`, which is the result of `json_to_perl(string)`, to an array.
But `json_to_perl()` didn't return an arrayref.

**json_to_perl** seems to be from this API: http://search.cpan.org/~bkb/JSON-Parse-0.31/lib/JSON/Parse.pod#json_to_perl
which returns according to the doc **either** an arrayref or a hashref.

Apparently it did return a hashref in your case, so you have to add the logic to deal with the HASH case. Which seems to be a single row.

```
if (ref $jsontext eq 'HASH') {
  # seems to be a single row
  $adrs->execute($url_ids[$currentUrlId], $jsontext->{'fmrp'}, $jsontext->'upa'}, $jsontext->'pda'}, $jsontext->'uid'}, $jsontext->'umrp'}, $jsontext->'ueid'});# || &die_clean("Couldn't execute\n$adsql\n".$db->errstr."\n" );
  $adrs2->execute($url_ids[$currentUrlId]);
  $currentUrlId++;
} elsif (ref $jsontext eq 'ARRAY') {
  foreach my $row (@$jsontext){
    $adrs->execute($url_ids[$currentUrlId], $row->{'fmrp'}, $row->{'upa'}, $row->{'pda'}, $row->{'uid'}, $row->{'umrp'}, $row->{'ueid'});# || &die_clean("Couldn't execute\n$adsql\n".$db->errstr."\n" );
    $adrs2->execute($url_ids[$currentUrlId]);
    $currentUrlId++;
  }
}
```